# How to get colour from image in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6

It seem silly question but I am new to react technology . Here I want to pick a color from image . For Example When User select a image to upload then I want to get all color which are used in image . If it possible please give me suggestion or solution or give me some resource ( video ) to complete my project

Thanks

Comment: Try this if you are still looking for something like that https://www.npmjs.com/package/get-image-colors

Answer (score 4):

The best way to do image processing is on Backend. But there are cases where you want to do theming on the device based on the image. In that case, you can use an iOS cocopod like [ChameleonFramework](https://cocoapods.org/pods/ChameleonFramework)  and create a Native Bridge to call iOS classes.

To create a Native Bridge you can check out [Native iOS Bridge for iOS and Android](https://medium.com/@abhisheknalwaya/react-native-bridge-for-ios-and-android-43feb9712fcb)

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure this suffices for your specifications, but [Color Thief](https://github.com/lokesh/color-thief) is a JS library which extracts the dominant color from an image. You would not be able to use it as such since it is created specifically for web and makes use of canvas, but there is not much code to it so with some work you could get this to work I guess ...

Answer (score 2):

I suggest that you could try Google cloud vision. After upload an image, Google returns relevant information including colors